# IE not accepting some html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in `SWITCH` case:

```
case 4:
      inp = document.createElement('SELECT');
      inp.id = "usrNameAttrListSel";
       var optStr = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < usrNameAttrFmts.length; i++) {
           optStr += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+usrNameAttrFmts[i].displayStr+"</option>";
           }
        optStr += "<option value='-1'>Other...</option>";
        inp.innerHTML = optStr; 

....
```

The above code is working fine with FF and Chrome.

Whereas in IE, the functioning is not proper.

Reason:

I added an alert - `alert(inp.innerHTML)`.
The actual result for the alert should be:

```
<option value="0">User-name</option>
<option value="1">Domain\User-name</option>
<option value="2">Domain/User-name</option>
<option value="3">User-name@Domain</option>
<option value="4">SonicWALL Aventail</option>
<option value="-1">Other...</option>
```

but in IE i m getting,

```
User-name</option>
<option value="1">Domain\User-name</option>
<option value="2">Domain/User-name</option>
<option value="3">User-name@Domain</option>
<option value="4">SonicWALL Aventail</option>
<option value="-1">Other...</option>
```

It omits, `<option value="0">`. Any alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

- Krishna

Comment: Please use proper code format!

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
case 4:
      inp = document.createElement('SELECT');
      inp.id = 'usrNameAttrListSel';
         for (var i = 0; i < usrNameAttrFmts.length; i++) {
           tmp = document.createElement('option');
           tmp.innerHTML = usrNameAttrFmts[i].displayStr;
           tmp.value = i;
           inp.appendChild(tmp);
        }
         tmp = document.createElement('option');
         tmp.innerHTML = 'Others';
         tmp.value = -1;
         inp.appendChild(tmp);
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to see in your code where it could go wrong, but you could try using double quotes for your HTML attributes:

```
 optStr += '<option value="' + i + '"> ...
```

Or

```
 optStr += "<option value=\""+i+"\">" ...
```

Maybe that helps.